# react native 0.60 cant download gradle5.4.1-all

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

i have new react native project with version 0.60 when i try to run the program try to Download https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip and result is error.

error:

```
ERROR: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 403 Request blocked by Privoxy"
```

Comment: having the same Issue here. Have found a solution???

Comment: @shayan Have you got any solution ?

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just 1.close your IDE(Android Studio) 2.delete .gradle folder in C:/Users/Your User.gradle in Windows and 3.open your IDE and enjoy